# Hue saturation intensity histogram plot

Tags: python

I am using pi with raspbian wheezy and python 2.7. I have an image in jpg format which I can read and convert to array. But I want to convert the image from RGB color model to HSI color model and then plot a histogram for the hue saturation and intensity parameters of the HSI image. I have tried to plot but I'm not sure about the accuracy of my results. I have included the code. Can anyone tell me how I can verify the output of my program.

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/ref.jpg")
array=np.asarray(img)
arr=(array.astype(float))/255.0
img_hsv = colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr[...,:3])

lu1=img_hsv[...,0].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.hist(lu1*360,bins=360,range=(0.0,360.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='r', label='Hue')
plt.title("Hue")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu2=img_hsv[...,1].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,2)                  
plt.hist(lu2,bins=100,range=(0.0,1.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='g', label='Saturation')
plt.title("Saturation")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu3=img_hsv[...,2].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,3)                  
plt.hist(lu3*255,bins=256,range=(0.0,255.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='b', label='Intesity')
plt.title("Intensity")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is a sample of my output histogram]

Comment: Photoshop does histograms. Take the image, do the same in Photoshop and compare. Possibly GIMP also does it and or other free software.

Comment: @ppumkin But as far as I know Photoshop does histograms but in the RGB colorspace not in HSI colorspace

Comment: Ohh right there is a Luminosity histogram but it does not show Hue, Saturation and Intensity. It just seems to show it all combined. This is new to me though and quite interesting.Although creating a new image with CMYK or LAB show a different histogram altogether. I wonder if this will help at all? http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1930490

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about signal processing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the complete edited code

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/testc.jpg")
array=np.asarray(img)
arr=(array.astype(float))/255.0
img_hsv = colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr[...,:3])

lu1=img_hsv[...,0].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.hist(lu1*360,bins=360,range=(0.0,360.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='r', label='Hue')
plt.title("Hue")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu2=img_hsv[...,1].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,2)                  
plt.hist(lu2,bins=100,range=(0.0,1.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='g', label='Saturation')
plt.title("Saturation")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu3=img_hsv[...,2].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,3)                  
plt.hist(lu3*255,bins=256,range=(0.0,255.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='b', label='Intesity')
plt.title("Intensity")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Verified results using Matlab

[image: Hue]

[image: Saturation]

[image: Intensity]

Comment: Awesome- You should make a GIT repo and put your code there for other people to use. This looks like some good work!